# Input and password for GhostBSD Live CD

Tags: boot, bsd, livecd

I downloaded GhostBSD Live CD but it is asking for an input and a password on boot. Live CDs usually don't need those. I could not find an answer in the GhostBSD Handbook.

Comment: What version of GhostBSD was this?

Answer (score 0):

As of the most recent GhostBSD LiveCD (release 21.05.11), you are not asked for a password when booting into the live CD system (the default boot action), nor when booting into single user mode.

If you do want to log in on a console on the live CD, then the username for the live system is `ghostbsd` without any password. I found no good documentation reference for this other than the [`build.sh`](https://github.com/ghostbsd/ghostbsd-build/blob/master/build.sh) script in the [`ghostbsd-build`](https://github.com/ghostbsd/ghostbsd-build) Git repository, which is used to actually *build* the live CD system.  In the script, a system user called `ghostbsd` [is added with no password](https://github.com/ghostbsd/ghostbsd-build/blob/master/build.sh#L163):

```bsh
chroot ${release} pw useradd ${liveuser} \
-c "GhostBSD Live User" -d "/usr/home/${liveuser}"\
-g wheel -G operator -m -s /usr/local/bin/fish -k /usr/share/skel -w none
```

(The variable `liveuser` has the value `ghostbsd` here, and it's the `-w none` at the end of the `useradd` command's list of arguments that selects no password for the account.)

When installing GhostBSD from the live CD, you get to choose the password for the root user, as well as the login details for a non-root account.

Answer (score -1):

user: `ghostbsd`

password: (nothing)